# FreeBSD ports / uhidd update

Tags: freebsd, ports

While attempting to update all my ports / installed ports with portmaster.  I receive an error code 1 while attempting to update uhidd-0.2.0_1 to uhidd-0.2.0_2.  Below is the error I receive, how do I provide the kernel source files?

```
portmaster -a
===>>> Gathering distinfo list for installed ports

===>>> Starting check of installed ports for available updates
===>>> Launching child to update dd_rescue-1.24 to dd_rescue-1.25

===>>> Port directory: /usr/ports/sysutils/dd_rescue

===>>> Launching 'make checksum' for sysutils/dd_rescue in background
===>>> Gathering dependency list for sysutils/dd_rescue from ports
===>>> No dependencies for sysutils/dd_rescue
===>>> Returning to update check of installed ports

===>>> Launching child to update pciutils-3.1.7 to pciutils-3.1.9

===>>> Port directory: /usr/ports/sysutils/pciutils

===>>> Launching 'make checksum' for sysutils/pciutils in background
===>>> Gathering dependency list for sysutils/pciutils from ports
===>>> Initial dependency check complete for sysutils/pciutils
===>>> Returning to update check of installed ports

===>>> Launching child to update uhidd-0.2.0_1 to uhidd-0.2.0_2

===>>> Port directory: /usr/ports/sysutils/uhidd

===>>> This port is marked IGNORE
===>>> requires kernel source files


===>>> If you are sure you can build it, remove the
       IGNORE line in the Makefile and try again.

===>>> Update for uhidd-0.2.0_1 failed
===>>> Aborting update

Terminated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says:

> ===>>> This port is marked IGNORE
>
> ===>>> requires kernel source files

You need to put system sources into `/usr/src`. You can obtain it from [SVN repo](http://svn.freebsd.org/base/release/), installation disk or [FTP](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/). And make sure that sources are corresponding to kernel you are running.

Comment: I'll try that.  I have other installations of PC BSD and I've updated the ports without this step.  Do you know any reasons which would cause this sort of "error" with this particular installation? Other installations were configured the same way.  Maybe just an update since the other installs.  But I dont think that makes much sense.

Comment: So, you are using PC-BSD, not FreeBSD?

Comment: I use both, and I have the same problem for both.

Comment: Well, you seem to have sources on your other machines. Check that `/usr/src/Makefile` and `/usr/src/sys/Makefile` are present.

Comment: It's working now.  I was just confused because I remember not installing the source files during the installation process.  Thanks.